# Writing an Android app purely in Frege

Tags: android, frege

I've been looking into this for a while now but there seems to be old solutions that focus on mainly calling frege from Java. Is there a way to write an complete app/Activity purely in Frege? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look here, it's most recent. http://mchav.github.io/frege-on-android/

Don't be shy to contact the author directly.

The short answer to your question: It is possible to write a complete App in Frege, except for a bit of glue code that implements the interface `android.app.Activity`. The reason being that we can't implement interfaces in Frege.

Comment: Great write-up. Thank you.